# Unable to parse JSON array API in Xamarin.Forms to ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am trying to parse a JSON Array with no success.I researched all possible solutions but none seems to work for my solution.

> This is the JSON returning from server:

`{"events":[{"url":"xxxxx","title":"xxxxx","date":"xxxx","time":"xxxx"},{"url":"xxxxx","title":"xxxxx","date":"xxxx","time":"xxxx"}]}`

> This is my RootObject class :

```
public class ChristmasEvent
{
    [JsonProperty("events")]
    public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [JsonProperty("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time")]
    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

> Web Service class

```
 private const string Url = "http://xxxx/events";
 private HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

 var apiResource = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(Url);

 var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChristmasEvent>>(apiResource);

 ObservableCollection<ChristmasEvent> christmasEvents = new ObservableCollection<ChristmasEvent>(tr);

 EventListView.ItemsSource = christmasEvents;
```

> XAML File

```
<ListView x:Name="EventListView">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout>
                 <Label Text="{Binding title}" />
                 <Label Text="{Binding date, StringFormat='{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}'}"/>
              </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
     </ListView>
```

I am unsure why this is not working and seeking to find what i am doing wrong..

Comment: please, always provide error that you get along with the question. It's hard to tell what exactly goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are trying to deserialize to a `List` of items, while you should deserialize as the item itself (as I can see from the JSON you provided):

```
var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChristmasEvent>(apiResource);
```

Then

```
var events = new ObservableCollection<Event>(tr.Events);
EventListView.ItemsSource = events;
```

2) You bind to lowercase properties. Bind to `Title` instead of `title` and `Date` instead of `date`. Or simply name your C# properties as lowercase. For example:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
```

3) Your `Date` property is declared as a `string`. But in your view you are trying to format it (with `StringFormat`) as a date. Make it a `DateTime` property. You may also want to change your `Time` property type to `TimeSpan`.

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Comment: That doesnt seem to be the issue. It is crashing at this point : `var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChristmasEvent>>(apiResource);` with error message : `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: With this `var tr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChristmasEvent>(apiResource);` how will i get the deserialize object as an Observable Collection to send to the view?

Comment: Simply. `EventListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Event>(tr.Events)` and upvote my answer if you find it helpful

Comment: That throws the following error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Comment: Where does it throw this? Which line? Does it happen when you are running the app or when you try to compile?

Comment: `List<AnonymousType#1>` means you are creating an anonymous type somewhere (like `new { property = "some_value" }` ). Show me that code

Comment: I reviewed my code and made some changes, it works now...thanks